# how to add Like symbol and by clicking on it, it should change colour i.e., like symbol in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, layout, drawable

[ 1. First, I have created a linear layout and I have added a picture in
    Drawable to the layout.

```
When I change this color, the overall linear layout color is changed
and the like symbol is invisible.
```

2. Second, I have placed in the Image view. its also not working. So,
   give me an Idea how to add that symbol and when clicked on it, it should change color. 
   The function should work similar to the facebook like icon.

   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai0v1.png)
   ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai0v1.png)

Comment: Please Read **[ask]**

Comment: I have updated the wrong png file so that it created a mistake. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Take a imageview in xml and set your `android:src="@mipmap/icon_video_play"` your image that you want to display at first attemp.

Then after clicking on imageview you should set image as -:

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  imageview.setImageResource(R.mipmap.newImage); //which you want to set

            }
        });
```

and take one thing into consideration the size of both the images should be same.

Comment: we will set one image on screen with Imageview. And then while clicking on that image it should replace with second image. i.e., the two must be different images but with same size. i have a doubt that where should we upload the images in the android studio.

Comment: where to upload means place them in drawable folder thats in android.